# Translate Object[] into Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following code that I translated into Kotlin:

```
if (intent.action == SMS_RECEIVED) {
    // retrieves a map of extended data from the intent
    val dataBundle = intent.extras
    if (dataBundle != null) {
        val mypdu = dataBundle.get("mypdu")

        mypdu.length... (NOT WORKING)

    }
}
```

Specifically, the creationg of the variable mypdu was like so in Java:

```
Object[] mypdu = (Object[]) dataBundle.get("mypdu");
```

And I cannot translate it into Kotlin. I cannot use the following:

```
val mypdu = dataBundle.get("mypdu") as (Object[])
```

And it seems like the IDE wants me to define the variable as Any, and then I cannot access its length property like I want to.
How can I translate this line into Kotlin?

Comment: In Java it should be of type Object[]

Comment: Without any casting, in Kotlin it decalres mypdu as Any, and then I cannot access its length property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
val mypdu = dataBundle.get("mypdu") as Array<Any?>
```

Note that I marked the elements of the `Array` as `Any?` because in Java we have no null safe compiler. That way you don't run into nasty NPEs later on.

Also to access the length of an array, use the `size` property, like so:

```
val length = mypdu.size
```